# Why the timer tick event keep calling the method twice in a row and not after 10 seconds each time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;

namespace ScrollLabelTest
{

    class SaveOldHtml
    {
        private static int count;
        private static Timer _timer = new Timer();
        private static string page;
        private static List<string> newText = new List<string>();

        public SaveOldHtml(string DirectoryToSave,int count, string contents)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(DirectoryToSave + "Page" + count.ToString("D6")
                                        + ".html", contents);
        }

        public SaveOldHtml(string DirectoryToSave, List<string> newTextList, int count)
        {
            using (StreamWriter myStream = new StreamWriter(DirectoryToSave + "newTextList" + count.ToString("D6")
                                        + ".txt"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < newTextList.Count; i++)
                {
                    myStream.WriteLine(newTextList[i]);
                }

            }
        }

        public static void Start()
        {
            _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            _timer.Interval = 10000;
            count = 5;
            LoadOldHtmlFiles();
            _timer.Start();
        }

        static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadOldHtmlFiles();
        }

        private static void LoadOldHtmlFiles()
        {

            page = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\OldHtml\page" + count.ToString("D6") + ".html");
            ListsExtractions.OffExtractions(@"c:\temp\OldHtml\page" + count.ToString("D6") + ".html", page, newText);
            count ++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the first time in the Start method i call LoadoldHtmlfiles once and then after 10 seconds i call it again in the timer tick event.
But then next time it's not waiting another 10 seconds but jump right away to the timer tick event and call LoadoldhmtlFiles again.

And i checkec few times and searched all the solution i'm calling the method Start onlny once in form1 constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `LoadOldHtmlFiles()` takes >= 10 seconds then your timer will fire it repeatedly. Stop the timer and restart it in the `_timer_Elapsed` method:

```
static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Stop();
    LoadOldHtmlFiles();
    _timer.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you place your main method inside timer tick function then your main method will be triggered after that timer is started, but to avoid this timer function being called again & again, stop this timer inside the timer tick function.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    <your main function>
}
```